# VBA Easier To Implement, ODBC vs OLEDB?

Tags: excel, vba, odbc, oledb

To create an ODBC connection in VBA, two things are required:

1. Create a ODBC data source
2. Add references in Excel

What I'd like to know is if OLEDB has fewer requirements and is easier to implement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OLEDB is the way to go as you'll probably be using ADODB for your queries etc.

Comment: I agree. OLEDB.  One thing to keep in mind for the provider in your connection string, on 32 bit XP you would use "provider=microsoft.jet.oledb.4.0" but in Win 7 64 bit use "provider=microsoft.ace.oledb.12.0"